# Error returning value with Zend fetchOne

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I want to return the number of active users like this

```
    $objSelect = $this->select()
                ->from("user", "COUNT(*) AS count" ) 
                ->where( "status = ?", 'Active' );
    $return = $this->fetchOne($objSelect);
    echo $return;
```

but this returns the error: Call to undefined method User_Model_User::fetchOne()

What am I missing here?

Comment: `fetchOne` is for DB Adapter,  not Table Gateway object. You are mixing two different DB abstraction classes.

Comment: Try `$return = $this->current();`

Comment: error undefined method current()

Comment: Sorry, `$return = $objSelect->current();`

Comment: @Anthony; no this gives me very strange behaviour. When I change to $return = $this->fetchRow($objSelect); and echo $return->toArray() I get the array 'count'=>value as expected. So I am curious why fetchOne is not working as expected when I only want to get the value.